# Cartesian Product on an Array of Strings using JAVA

Tags: java

I'm not sure about the title of the question, please feel free to edit it!

Anyway, here is the problem description:

I have a data structure, to hold relational information between two pairs:

```
Class Relation
{
    Public String Source;
    Public String Destination;
    Public String Relate;
}
```

In my program, I have the following initialization to encode different relations between two sets of entities:

```
String []Subjects = new String [10]; // Consider having S1, S2, S3
String []Objects = new String [10]; // Consider having O1, O2
Relation []AllRelations = new Relation[100];
//Consider having the following rerlations in AllRelations array:
/*
S1 Read O1
S1 Write O1
O1 Delete S2
O1 Add S2
S2 Update S3
S3 Execute O3
*/
```

I need to iterate through the AllRelations array, to find all possible relations. The output should be an array of strings where each string holds the possible relations between two given entities. There is no need to have the Source and Destination in the output array.

In the example given, the output should be something like:

```
Read-Delete-Update-Execute

Read-Add-Update-Execute

Write-Delete-Update-Execute

Write-Add-Update-Execute
```

I was trying to solve this problem with an iterative approach "loops", but I failed. Also, I'm trying to consider recursion and I have no idea how to start.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What you actually have here is a graph, where the vertices are "subjects" and "objects", and the edges are relations. Your goal is to start from each vertex, and continue along each path in the grid (presumably until you can't visit a new edge.) Moving along an edge means taking the current "Destination", and finding a "Relation" that has the same string as its "Source". Note what the relation is for that object, and then repeat, until you can't anymore. You'll need a way to keep track of "visited" relations.

Comment: @sp00m; I'm not having the IDE on this machine, but here is the code. what is your concern?

Comment: @dlev; you are right. But how to do it, where to start as I'm not experience in graphing with Java.

Comment: The best approach might be to research some basic graph generation and traversal algorithms. You can then code those, and by then you're almost done, since all you need to do is convert your current data into the appropriate format, and then call your newly written methods.

Comment: @dlev you might want to have your comment as the possible answer.